# autocomplete textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my jquery code.

```
  $.ajax({
       url: '/api/LLCReport/GetClientRegionsList',
       async: true,
       success: function (regionList) {
          $("#txtSearchBox").autocomplete(regionList);
       }
  });
```

and the regionlist is like

```
displaname     path
-------------  ----------
western        region-western
eastern        region-eastern
```

here my problem is autocomplete function not working. In search criteria i need to get like below

```
 Eastern
    reggion-eastern
 Western
    region-eastern
```

means displayname first and its path followed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: View this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery UI the [custom display](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) comes out of the box